# Add a source text to the map but don't function

Tags: r

I created a map with that code

```
tm_shape(map, bbox = bbox_new) +
  tm_borders("grey", lwd = 1) +
  tm_fill("ratio") +
 tm_layout(legend.position = c(0.825,0.4), legend.bg.color = "aliceblue", 
            title= "fertility rate in Switzerland", 
            title.position = c('centre', 'top'))  + tm_shape(water_shp) + tm_fill("lightskyblue1") +
    tm_markers(text = "city")
```

```
+ tm_text("Source:swisstopo", position= c(0.25, 0.85)) + tm_text("Author: Pat Madriz", position = C(0.2,0.85)
```

seems not work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`tm_text` is for adding multiple text labels to features, for example if you have a name attribute to your polygons and you want to put the name on each polygon on the map.

Try `tm_credits`:

```
library(tmap)
library(sf)
example(st_read) # get the nc object
tm_shape(nc) + 
   tm_polygons("BIR79") +
   tm_legend(legend.position=c(0,0)) +
   tm_credits("Map by me\nI made this")
```

[image]

There are options to size and style the text, align this way and that etc.